# How to go and watch complete game replays?

Tags: league-of-legends

I'm looking to see some full game replays in League of Legends (that are not my friends' game)

Those "Featured games" in the starter slider are always in progress, and what I'm looking for is to get in a random game that is still on the character select screen. (or at least still in the 3 minutes buffer)

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.  There are three types of games you can spectate:

- The featured games on the main page
- A game that someone in your friend's list is participating in
- A custom game that has spectator slots open

Comment: So I guess my only way in would be to get in a custom game. Thanks @timlan!

Comment: There was a site awhile back that allowed more general viewing.  Not sure if the author carried it forward elsewhere: http://www.reddit.com/r/leagueoflegends/comments/vr24f/league_theater_a_website_for_searchingbrowsing/

Answer (score 2):

http://www.leaguereplays.com/ is a third party application which allows you to record your own games and watch em aswell as ones recorded by other people by manually downloading them

that's the closest thing i can think of to what you're looking for

Answer (score 1):

Download LOL Recorder from this site http://www.leaguereplays.com/ as mentioned in previous answers.  For the best results though you should go into the options (the cog wheel in the corner of the main page on LOL Recorder) and turn on:

- Record While Spectating
  and
- Record All Matches in Specmode

What this will do is allow you to record while just purely spectating as you asked, but will also give you the recording in the mode in which you spectate (i.e. Specmode), if the Record in Specmode box is not checked, you will only see health bars of friendly and enemy champions within a certain proximity of yourself, before they disappear, you can't see the total gold of both teams, and the UI just doesn't look as nice.

If you are unaware of what specmode is I will elaborate.  Specmode includes:

- A very nice UI that allows you to see BOTH teams all the time (not just your own)
- Allows easy view of how long wards will last
- The UI also has a nice centerpiece that allows you to see the gold currently owned by each champion (even enemies) and how much they have acquired throughout the entire game, as well as all items owned by all champions.
- Rewind and fast forward mode
- A camera that if left untouched will follow the action and jump around the map to different champions without you touching a button (called directed camera)
- Total gold obtained by each time for easy telling which team has the gold lead
- An easy counter for how many towers each team has taken down
- Colorblind mode for anyone that is colorblind, allowing the purple team to become the red team
- More I'm sure that I just can't think of

Record in specmode will also allow all the games you play yourself to be recorded in this fashion, for very improved reviewing of your own games.  I hope I've provided sufficient information on this subject and that you enjoy LOL Recorder and Specmode recordings.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.leaguereplays.com/ is safe riot even wrote an article about how well it worked

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! This answer brings nothing that have not already been said. Please avoid duplicating content and only provide answers that add something new.

Comment: Hey Serion442, welcome to Arqade! Thanks for taking the time to answer a question! Normally when we see an answer that we agree with, we upvote it; we don't need to reaffirm the correct answer by repeating it. Once you gain the privilege to upvote, it'll seem more clear. Otherwise, is there anything you'd like to add that isn't covered by the other answers, such as a screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

Look up the persons ign on most 3rd party sites will have a button you can click to watch that persons game.

A few sites you can try for this are:
lolnexus.com
na.op.gg