# How do I watch a specific player's game?

Tags: league-of-legends

I used to be able to look at the Top Challenger Players ([as pointed too in the answer for this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/77792/how-to-go-and-watch-complete-game-replays)), and click on them, but I got into Ranked and it doesn't work anymore).

How do I watch a specific player's game?

Answer (score 1):

Currently you will have to use third party sites to get the proper data required to spectate via Client on specific players.
It's pretty much the same as normal spectating but you have a bit of extra work to do. If you're 100% committed to spectating a user, this will be the best approach aside from attempting to add them as a friend.

Here is a source that will will assist you through doing so.

> First go to http://www.op.gg/spectate/pro/
>   Find any game you are interested in
>   Click on spectate
>   Open the downloaded bat file with notepad
>   Seek for this line https://i.stack.imgur.com/WlvoJ.png and copy it exemple "League of Legends.exe" "8394" "LoLLauncher.exe" "" "spectator 110.45.191.11:80 h+UcrXMrZarLQmY1WUJxfP9+hSxV2I9j 1059299827 KR"
>   Now replace "League of Legends.exe" with your lol setup directory exemple "C:\Riot Games\League of Legends\RADS\solutions\lol_game_client_sln\releases\0.0.1.4\deploy\League of Legends.exe"
>   copy and past the edited line into the Windows run application (start -> run past and hit ok) https://i.stack.imgur.com/bu77t.png
>   now LOL will open and start spectating
>   few notes:
>   Korean names are not displayed correctly
>   You don't need to open lol and login for this
>   Sometimes your client became black screen restart it
>   You can access to run program quickly by hiting WindowsKey+R     (http://content.gcflearnfree.org/topics/229/start_keyboard_windows_key.jpg)
>   Enjoy

SOURCE: http://www.reddit.com/r/leagueoflegends/comments/1v3z8m/spectate_pro_korean_player_soloqueue_or_5v5_using/

Answer (score -1):

Unless they are featured on the client or in your friends list, there is no way to look up a specific player and spectate their game.